Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS Released
I have three Ubuntu 22.04 LTS workstations in an offline environment(air-gapped). I need to be able to get the latest updates and have all those machines patched. What is the best method for doing this? Is it recommended to try using apt offline? I am open to suggestions and feedback.
